# The best way to check for write_settings permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

Can I check the write_settings permission using

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {...}
```

the docs talk about `Settings.System.canWrite(context)` but this way is very bad 'cause have to check every time what is Android version. :(

Seems to me this have no problem. Anyone knows with sure?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

These two verifications do practically the same thing, except that you need the Android Support dependency in order to use `ContextCompat`, whereas `Settings.System` is part of the default Android SDK. Note that `Context` class can check for permissions too.

By the way, electing one way as *the best* way to check for permissions is rather opinion-based, and it's not something the stackoverflow community fancies too much. You should compare the possibilities and choose the one that fits you best.

> but this way is very bad 'cause have to check every time what is Android version. :(

You'll get used to it.

Comment: Thx, actually what I really wanted was know if the 2 forms worked, but I did not find a better title to my question :)